# DOM `pointermove` event fires twice with same coordinate on iPad+Apple Pencil

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, dom-events

While I was fiddling with [Pointer Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/), I found that `pointermove` events fires twice on exactly same coordinate if I touch iPad with Apple Pencil.

[The specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#the-pointermove-event) says:

> A user agent MUST fire a pointer event named pointermove when a pointer changes coordinates. Additionally, when a pointer changes button state, pressure, tangential pressure, tilt, twist, or contact geometry (e.g. width and height) and the circumstances produce no other pointer events defined in this specification then a user agent MUST fire a pointer event named pointermove.

So I quickly wrote a simple "event logger", which just dumps all the properties of `PointerEvent` to the textarea.

https://jsfiddle.net/xb8jgptw/18/show

If I swipe the screen with Apple Pencil, `pointermove` fires twice on every coordinate, without changing any properties:
[image: swipe with stylus]

With my finger, it works as expected (**ONLY** fires when a pointer changes one of its properties):
[image: swipe with finger]

Though it is easy to handle this problem (just ignore every other event), I just want to know why is this happening or if this is the expected behavior.